# Automating simulation in cadence virtuso

Tags: analog, cadence

I want to find out delay of a 16 bit adder designed in cadence virtuso icfb tool for a large number of input values and Vdd. I know how to simulate the design with a given input and find delays using delay function in waveform calculator. How can I do this analysis for a large number of inputs, say 1000?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Cadence icfb comes with a built in scripting language called "ocean" that I would use for this. You can export an ocean script describing your circuit from within ADE, then wrap it in a loop that varies the input and VDD as you wish. At the end of each run through the loop you measure the output and write it to a file. Once it has run 1000 times you should end up with what you want. The ocean documentation should ship with your Cadence installation, and there's a nice introductory video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hrfdK3bP-Y

Answer (score 0):

you can add all the possible inputs( you basically create the truth table for your adder) using stimuli where you have a periodic input with different frequency for each input and different input bits, like this waveform 
[image]